# NULL constraint after attribute in CREATE TABLE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to figure out what this NULL is doing. Here a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
       bla VARCHAR NULL
);
```

So I tried to figure out wether this is set to be the default value, but it is null as default wether I put it there or not, right?

Also I wondered if it has to stay null (for whatever reason) but when I tried to insert a value it was possible anyway. So does it do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html):

> **NULL**
>
> The column **is allowed to contain null values**. This is the default.

You could write:

```
INSERT INTO test(bla)
VALUES (NULL);
-- it holds NULL

INSERT INTO test(bla)
VALUES (default);
-- it holds NULL

INSERT INTO test(bla)
VALUES ('a');
-- it holds 'a'
```

You could also omit column:

```
CREATE TABLE test2(bla VARCHAR NULL, col2 INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO test2(col2) VALUES (1);
-- it contains NULL, 1
```

---

If you specify column as:

```
CREATE TABLE test(bla VARCHAR NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO test(bla) VALUES (NULL);
-- error
```

**EDIT:**

You don't have to specify `NULL` explicitly.

```
CREATE TABLE test(bla VARCHAR);
```

is the same as:

```
CREATE TABLE test (bla VARCHAR NULL);
```

Comment: Ah okay! Really helpful, thank you! Will accept answer as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

You are parameterizing the column can be NULL